# How to increase the performance of this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GetDataForReports]
(
     @userID            INT,
     @startDate  DATE,
     @endDate    DATE,
     @reportType INT,  -- 1: Search, 2: UnsuccessfulSearch, 3: SkuViewed
     @eventLabel NVARCHAR(400) = NULL,
     @level      INT           = NULL,
     @pageNumber INT           = NULL,
     @pageSize   INT           = NULL,
     @isAll      TINYINT       = NULL   -- 1 for exporting reports
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF ISNULL(@isAll,0) = 0
    BEGIN
        IF @level = 1
        BEGIN
            SELECT  
                EventLabel, 
                TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER() 
            FROM
                (SELECT DISTINCT EventLabel
                 FROM ClickStreamData WITH(NOLOCK)
                 WHERE EventDate BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
                   AND UserID = @userID  
                   AND EventCategoryID = CASE   
                                            WHEN @reportType = 1
                                              THEN 1
                                            WHEN @reportType = 2    
                                              THEN 5
                                            WHEN @reportType = 3
                                              THEN 2    
                                         END
                   AND Eventlabel = ISNULL(@eventLabel, Eventlabel)
                ) T
            ORDER BY 
                EventLabel
                OFFSET ((@pageNumber - 1) * @pageSize) ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @pageSize ROWS ONLY
        END
```

Comment: What kind of performance issues are you running into? slow? locking?. Check the query execution plan to determine where are the bottle necks. Did you check if there are indexes required?

Answer (score 4):

1. Ensure an index is on UserId and EventDate and possibly also EventLabel. Press the "Include the Actual Execution Plan" button in SSMS and use it to search for missing indexes - this will hopefully agree with me and you can fine tune the indexing exactly for the query.
2. Sorry I must add: Please do not use NOLOCK, it can return inaccurate results, unless you measure performance and really need it. There are plenty of articles on the web as to why it is bad, here is one of them http://www.jasonstrate.com/2012/06/the-side-effect-of-nolock/. The alternative to NOLOCK is generally setting up the DB correctly in terms of locking strategy and lock promotion settings.

Comment: upvoated for pointing out about nolock

Comment: I would also like to add that if you check the execution plan and have all the necessary indexes, and its still slow, you might like to check that your tempdb is configured correctly on your server. This type of query could use tempdb quite a bit behind the scenes, so if its fragmented, short of space or you don't have one file per cpu core, or sharing disk io bandwidth with other apps, then your entire server could be slower than  it would be otherwise.